# Unable to implement shared animation transition

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am trying to implement shared animation transition when someone clicks on recycler view item and navigate to detail activity.I want to show effect on image view when its size increases in detail activity.There  is no transition effect is showing.

Below is my code:

**themes.xml**

```
 <style name="Theme.ITunes" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_dark</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
</style>
```

**item_layout.xml**

```
  <ImageView
           android:layout_width="200dp"
           android:layout_height="170dp"
           android:id="@+id/trackImg"
           android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:transitionName="imageTransition"/>
```

**activity_video_detail.xml**

```
 <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:id="@+id/imgDetail"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:transitionName="imageTransition"/>
```

**VideoAdapter.class**

```
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(context, VideoDetail.class);
            i.putExtra("name",model.getTrackName());
            i.putExtra("image",model.getArtworkUrl100());
            ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context,holder.trackImg,"transition");
            context.startActivity(i,options.toBundle());
        }
    });
```

**VideoDetail.class**

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

    if(item.getItemId() ==  android.R.id.home){
        onBackPressed();
     }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    supportFinishAfterTransition();
}
```

What can I try to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

The string passed to `makeSceneTransitionAnimation` should match `transitionName` in the receiving activity, so use `imageTransition` instead of `transition`

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context,holder.trackImg,"imageTransition");
```

It's also a good idea to use string resources to get rid of magic strings